# How to create a UI with horizontal and vertical scrolling in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.ios

I have a design with vertical and horizontal scrolling.I need to add two lists in to the same page.So I have used bindable layout for this but the scrolling is not working on this. Please help me on the below. I am stuck on this for a week.

Here is my View and ViewModel

```
     <StackLayout BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">
            <StackLayout
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="1"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource.TestList2}"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label
                    Margin="0" WidthRequest="75"
                    FontSize="16"
                    HeightRequest="58"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    MaxLines="3"
                    Text="{Binding Subname}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout x:Name="layout1"
        Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,0,0,0"
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource.TestList}"
        Orientation="Vertical">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                            <Label
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="3"
                        Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <StackLayout
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding classes}"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <RadioButton WidthRequest="75" 
                                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                     IsChecked="{Binding IsFailed}"/>
                                           
                                            <Entry Placeholder="Subject" 
                                                   IsVisible="{Binding IsEntry}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                      
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel

```
      public class ListViewVM:BaseViewModel
       {
         private TestClass _listSource;
         public TestClass ListSource
         {
        get { return _listSource; } 
        set { _listSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListSource");
        }
    }

    //public 

    public ListViewVM()
    {
        TestClass kk=new TestClass();
        kk.BindData();
        ListSource = new TestClass();
        ListSource.TestList =new List<TestName>(kk.TestList);
        ListSource.TestList2= new List<TestSubject>( kk.TestList2);
        ListSource.TestList.ForEach(x => x.classes=kk.TestList2);
        var item = ListSource;
    }}
```

Model

```
 public class TestClass
{
    public List<TestName> TestList { get; set; }
    public List<TestSubject> TestList2 { get; set; }

    public void BindData() 
    {
        TestList = new List<TestName>() { new TestName {id=1,name="Jo"},
         new TestName {id=2,name="Annie" },
         new TestName {id=3,name="Alex" }};

        TestList2 = new List<TestSubject>() { new TestSubject { id=1,Subname="Maths"},
        new TestSubject { id=2,Subname="Physics"},
        new TestSubject { id=2,Subname="Chemestry"},
        new TestSubject { id=2,Subname="Other",IsEntry=true}};
    
    }
}
public class TestName
{
    public int id { get; set; }  
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<TestSubject> classes { get; set; }
}
public class TestSubject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Subname { get; set; }

    public bool IsFailed {get;set;}
    public bool IsOthersSelected { get; set; } 
    public bool IsEntry { get; set; }
}
```

Current UI

[image]

Some conditions is there , the user should select only one option from each row, but in my design they can select multiple option. If I add the RadioButton without that stacklayout the selection case is working but that time I cannot add the Entry field.If the user select "other" , then I need display an input field at the end along with "other" option for adding the other subject . So that field also mandatory for me.

Comment: ListView and CollectionView have built in support for scrolling.  StackLayout does not.  You either need to add a ScrollView control or switch to a control that has built in scrolling support.

Comment: But adding CollectionView and ListView in same page causing space issues

Comment: then try the other suggestion I gave you